# Get the length of a Dictionary in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, dictionary

I want to retrieve how many items there are in the Dictionary array:

[image]

But doing the following does not seem to yield **4** as it should:

```
Dim showNumber As Integer = tmpShows.Length
```

The code for the Dictionary I have is this:

```
Dim all = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
Dim info = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(3).ChildNodes(2).InnerText
info!Shows = From tag In .SelectNodes(".//a[@class='thickbox']")
             Select New With {.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}

Dim tmpShows = all.Item(info!Station)
Dim showNumber As Integer = tmpShows.Length
```

What am I missing in order to get the **4** length I am looking for?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    Dim all = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

    For Each channel In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='channel_row']")
        Dim info = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        skipFirstShow = False

        With channel
            info!Logo = .SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value
            info!Channel = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(3).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
            info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(3).ChildNodes(2).InnerText

            Dim style As String = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[2]").Attributes("style").Value

            If InStr(style.ToLower, "width: 0px;") <> 0 Then skipFirstShow = True

            info!Shows = From tag In .SelectNodes(".//a[@class='thickbox']")
                         Select New With {.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}
            'Select New With {.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}
        End With

        all.Add(info!Station, info.Item("Shows"))
        theLogoURL(theCount) = "https://example.org" & Trim(info.Item("Logo"))
        theChannelNum(theCount) = Trim(info.Item("Channel"))
        theStationCallLetters(theCount) = Trim(info.Item("Station"))

        Dim Shows As String = ""
        Dim ShowsDetail As String = ""
        Dim tmpShows = all.Item(info!Station)
```

Comment: This question has a high search engine ranking for a simple lookup query like *"C# length dictionary"* (yes, C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this to get my count...

```
 Dim intXShows As Integer = 0

 For Each item In tmpShows
    intXShows += 1
 Next
```

Comment: Couldn't something be said about the efficiency?

Answer (score 7):

Use *Count* instead of *length*.

**Example:**

```
Dim showNumber As Integer = tmpShows.Count
```

Comment: @StealthRT, try this **tmpShows.ToList().Count**

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Still a **0** :o/

Comment: @StealthRT, seems you are doing something wrong in your code. What type of data you are getting when you see that in quick watch?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Updated my OP with the image of the quick watch.

Comment: @StealthRT, also post the full quick watch view of **tmpShows**

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Updated again with that request.

Comment: @StealthRT, as you can see the **tmpShows** is a null object,just pass that condition in debugger and than take a screenshot of quick watch. Right now the code doesn't executed yet.

Comment: did you try the `.ToList().Count`?

Comment: @StealthRT, can you also post **tmpShows.ToList()** with quick watch?

Comment: and what namespace are you using, I don't have that special `.Item` on my dictionary

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Done. Updated OP.

Comment: @StealthRT: [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f.aspx) is the correct property.

Comment: @StealthRT: Count always works. Try reducing your example to something that is self-contained and as a result can be reproduced standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your declaration like this:

```
Dim all as New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
```

Instead of:

```
Dim all = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
```

And then call `Count`, `Length`, etc.

Also try using a `ForEach` loop to get the count of your `all` variable.